# How can I write Traffic Light logic based on Induction Loop data in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I have a simple traffic light intersection in which I have already set the traffic light logic. Suppose the vehicle density is increasing in one road and I want to retrieve this data in Omnet and use the C++ logic to direct the traffic lights to change state. Is it possible to do this in Omnet++?
In short I am looking to control the traffic using the network information obtained by running SUMO and coupling through SUMO. Is it possible to control the traffic through Omnet++? If yes, then can you tell me an example of how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Veins already includes some TraCI commands to retrieve the state of a SUMO simulation, as well as to change traffic lights. SUMO includes many more TraCI commands which should be able to do what you describe. You would just need to implement them in Veins as well, building on what is already there.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I implemented entire logic using Python TracI library. I was able to successfully generate the traffic model based on the requirements. Maybe I would come back to Veins someday with better approach.