# Omnet++ issue with getleader()

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have been trying to retrieve the data of preceding vehicle via getleader() [[Calculating the distance between the current vehicle and the preceding vehicle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249351/calculating-the-distance-between-the-current-vehicle-and-the-preceding-vehicle]) and then send it out as wsm to other vehicles. Issue is that my Simulation stops as soon as the function sendleaderdata() is called with the following error in Mingw:

```
 <stderr><![CDATA[Error: Answered with error to command 0xa4: Wrong position in requestMessage after dispatching command. Expected command length was 25 but 16 Bytes were read.
```

My sendleaderdata() :

```
{      std::pair <std::string,double> leader = traciVehicle->getLeader(0.0);
       int leaderId = std::stoi (leader.first ,nullptr) ;
       double leaderpos= leader.second;
       printf ("Leaderpos %.1f" , leaderpos);
       std::string leadmsg = std::to_string(leaderpos);
       WaveShortMessage *wsm = new WaveShortMessage ("leaderdata");
       wsm-> setWsmData(leadmsg.c_str());
       sendDown(wsm->dup());
       delete wsm;
}
```

sendleaderdata() is being called periodically via an event with an interval of 1.0s in handleSelfMsg().
I have already tried debugging but it just doesn't go beyond the first line of sendleaderdata(). 
Would be nice if someone can help me. Thank you in advance :)

Edit: I am using the V 0.32.0 and here is the screenshot of command window: [Cmnd win](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ThD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using code that was written for a different version of SUMO. As neither you nor the answer you are referencing are giving which SUMO version they are asking (or answering) for, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of command window but your answer definitely makes sense. Thanks :)